# flutter listview alphabet index

Tags: listview, flutter, alphabet

How to get the finger movement event in flutter like 'recyclerview alphabet index in android' check the sample image.

I have created a Positioned alphabet index listview but I can't find the current index in DragUpdate.

```
            var alphabet = ["#","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

            new Positioned(
                top: .0,
                left: 1,
                bottom: 10,
                width: 55,
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: alphabet.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


                        return new GestureDetector(
                            onVerticalDragUpdate:
                                (DragUpdateDetails detail) {
                              setState(() {
                                _barOffset += detail.delta.dy;
                              });

                              print("$detail");
                              print("Update ${alphabet[index]}");
                            },

                             onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails detail) {
                              print("onVerticalDragStart");
                              print("Start ${alphabet[index]}");
                            },
                            onVerticalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails detail) {
                              print("onVerticalDragEnd");
                              print("End ${alphabet[index]}");
                            },
                            onTap: () => print(alphabet[index]),
                            child: new Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 6.5),
                              height: 15.0,
                              child: new Text('${alphabet[index]}'),
                            ));
                      }),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/side_header_list_view is somewhat similar

Comment: or maybe this one: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/draggable_scrollbar

Comment: This is exactly that what you seek:
https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_list_scroll_view

Answer (score 4):

Do the following steps to achieve this.

**Step1:** Gesture detector for A to Z slider

1. onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate
2. onVerticalDragStart: _onVerticalDragStart

**Step 2:** Add the speech bubble for scrolled alphabet.

**Step 3:** calculate the index with vertically scrolled position

```
if ((_offsetContainer + details.delta.dy) >= 0 &&
        (_offsetContainer + details.delta.dy) <=
            (_sizeheightcontainer - _heightscroller)) {
    _offsetContainer += details.delta.dy;
    posSelected =
        ((_offsetContainer / _heightscroller) % _alphabet.length).round();
    _text = _alphabet[posSelected];
    if (_text != _oldtext) {
        for (var i = 0; i < exampleList.length; i++) {
            if (_text
                    .toString()
                    .compareTo(exampleList[i].toString().toUpperCase()[0]) == 0) {
                _controller.jumpTo(i * _itemsizeheight);
                break;
            }
        }
        _oldtext = _text;
    }
}
```

For the complete implementation, check this:

https://github.com/sanjaysingh1990/AtoZSliderCustomized.git

Comment: hi i have just implemented the logic given above related to A to Z slider.

Comment: please share your lib to dartpub

Answer (score 2):

To have something like this:

[image: Exemple]

### Initial part

To solve this problem you need to create a custom widget that will return a `LayoutBuilder` who contain a `Stack` who contain a `ListView` at first layer and a `Container` at second layer (as scroller) on right (to put your scroller on right add `alignment: Alignment.topRight` to your `Stack`).

### Make move the scroller

To move the scroller add a `GestureDetector` and catch the `onVerticalDragUpdate` add use a custom property `_offsetContainer` to the one you will add the `details.delta.dy` (from the event) to make your scroller going down and up.

### Make move the ListView from the scroller

#### First part

After that you need to add a `ScrollController` to your `ListView` to control it's vertical movement (as `controller` property).

Ok now you need to know multiples stuff to continue:

- Your alphabet array lenght
- The height size of your `ListView`
- The height size of scroller
- Have an item collection sorted (logic)
- The height size of one item of your `ListView` (that we will call `_itemsizeheight`)

The goal to reach now is to make move your `ListView`at the first item in the list starting with the alphabet letter selected.

For that you need some maths and some tricks.

To calculate your `ListView` height you need to take the body height and remove the heigth of other widget. But to simplify here we will say that your `ListView` take all the body height. Then it correspond to `contrainsts.biggest.height`(Thanks to the `LayoutBuilder`).

To calculate your scroller height you can do it efficiently and divide the body height by the number of letter in your alphabet array.
`_heightscroller = contrainsts.biggest.height / _alphabet.length;`

#### Second part

We will first make the scroller show the letter index with a `Text` widget. Then add a `Text` widget to your controller and add a `_text` property in your custom widget to allow you to change it with the `setState` function.

In your `onVerticalDragUpdate` you have your `_offset` value that correspond to your scroller position. Then you need to make a 'simple' calc to find to witch index of your alphabet array it correspond.

```dart
_text = _alphabet[((_offsetContainer / _heightscroller) % _alphabet.length).round()];
```

#### Third part

Now you know the letter then it will be easy to make move your `ListView`.
First get the index in your list of the first element that correspond to the letter selected.

Example:

```dart
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < widget.items.length; i++) {
   if (widget.items[i].toString().trim().length > 0 &&
       widget.items[i].toString().trim().toUpperCase()[0] ==
       _text.toString().toUpperCase()[0]) {
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Now that you have your index just use your `ScrollController` to move your `ListView`.

```dart
_scrollController.animateTo(index * _itemsizeheight,                         
   duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   curve: Curves.ease);
```

### Make move the scroller from the ListView

Ok now it's working but we need to make move the scroller too isen't ? I mean i dont want that it stay on the  `V` letter when the `ListView` will display me `A` letter items.

How to do this ?

In your init function just after that you set your `ScrollController` add an 
`_scrollController.addListener(onscrolllistview);` to know when the user will scroll directly in the `ListView`.

In your `onscrolllistview`function you need some calculation to get the first item displayed and the last item displayed.

```dart
var indexFirst = ((_scrollController.offset / _itemsizeheight) % widget.items.length).floor();
var indexLast = ((((_heightscroller * _alphabet.length) / _itemsizeheight).floor() + indexFirst) - 1) % widget.items.length;
```

Perfect now you can easly know witch letter you need to display on your scroller and then know where it need to be (change it's offset).

```dart
var i = _alphabet.indexOf(fletter);
        if (i != -1) {
          setState(() {
            _text = _alphabet[i];
            _offsetContainer = i * _heightscroller;
          });
```

The `fletter` var will depend of the direction of the scroll.

If you are going downward it will be :

`var fletter = widget.items[indexLast].toString().toUpperCase()[0];`

If you are going upward it will be :

`var fletter = widget.items[indexFirst].toString().toUpperCase()[0];`

### Fix the scroller animation

Ok now if you put a `debugPrint` you will can see that the `onscrolllistview` function is called all time even when we are using the scroller. This is a problem. Then how to fix that ?

You need to know when you finished to move when all your animations are finished.

Then just add a `_animationcounter` property in your class.
You will increment it when you are moving your scroller and decrement it when one animation is finished.
Like this:

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < widget.items.length; i++) {
   if (widget.items[i].toString().trim().length > 0 &&
       widget.items[i].toString().trim().toUpperCase()[0] ==
       _text.toString().toUpperCase()[0]) {
     _animationcounter++;
     _scrollController.animateTo(i * _itemsizeheight,
             duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
             curve: Curves.ease) .then((x) => {_animationcounter--});
             break;
        }
   }
```

Now just surround your code of scroller moving in `onscrolllistview` by

```dart
if (_animationcounter == 0) {/*...your code...*/}
```

#### PS

You need to take care of you `_offsetContainer` to not go out of bound.
You cand do it like this by exemple:

```dart
if ((_offsetContainer + details.delta.dy) >= 0 &&
                  (_offsetContainer + details.delta.dy) <=
                      (context.size.height - _heightscroller)) {
                _offsetContainer += details.delta.dy;
    }
```

This solution can be probably optimized (not send multiple animation, add var make less calcs). You can find a complete implementation here :
[AtoZscrollflutter](https://github.com/oom-/AtoZscrollflutter-)

Comment: Hey OOM saw your code, any chance if we can render AtoZSlider under the SinglechildScrollview without using the Expanded widget. I am trying to add the widget inside column and under the singlechild scrollview to we can scroll the page.
Do we have any solution for this one instead of not giving the  static height

Comment: Hello  @SagarAcharya, sorry this post is a little bit old... so I'm not fresh anymore on this subject. But I think that it was an issue with the SingleChildScrollview... I can't remember what it was... All of the code logic turn around the fact to retrieve the current height and apply "indexing" based on the item's height and first letters. So the only way (at the period) was to find the actual height (static or dynamic). Try to find some other libraries and check if they found a new way to do it (and let me know).

Comment: Yes currently i am doing the same, dynamic height based on the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
         Material(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: alphabet.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var letterHeight = (SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 100) / 33;
                return GestureDetector(
                  onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails detail) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentPosition += detail.delta.dy;
                    });
                  },
                  onVerticalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails detail) {
                    setState(() {
                      int letters = currentPosition > 0
                          ? ((currentPosition + letterHeight) / letterHeight)
                              .round()
                          : ((currentPosition - letterHeight) / letterHeight)
                              .round();
                      if (index + letters < alphabet.length) {
                        index += letters;
                      } else {
                        index = alphabet.length;
                      }

                      currentPosition = 0;
                      currentLetter = alphabet[index];
                    });
                  },
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentLetter = alphabet[index];
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: letterHeight,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('${alphabet[index]}'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
```